# Jquery load more button for Wordpress with Custom post types

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to add a load more button to my wordpress website, to load my custom post types. So far I have been able to make it load the posts.

The problem is that every time I load more posts it replaces the first batch witch the second and so on. I want it to append every consecutive batch of posts to the first batch until the are no more (max_num_pages) posts left after that the button should deactivate.

How would I go about achieving this? Suggestions and improvements will be greatly appreciated. This is what I have so far.

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<button class="load-more">load more</button>

var clicks = 0;

$(".load-more").click(function(){
clicks += 1;

if(clicks < 2){
$("#div1").load("http://mysite.nl/loadmore/");
    } else if(clicks > 1) {
        $("#div1").load("http://mysite.nl/loadmore/page/" + clicks);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `$("#div1").load()` will replace all the HTML in `#div1`. I'd say load your new data on a hidden element then `.append()` that new data to `#div1`.

#### Or

...perhaps you can save the existing `#div1` HTML to a variable:

```
var foo = $('#div1').html();
```

then load your new data and afterwards `.prepend()` the original:

```
$('#div1')
    .load("http://...")
    .prepend(foo);
```